# How to join series of file together side by side without seeing any gap between columns in output?

Tags: linux, command

How can I join several files together in way that there not be any gap between columns in final out put? as an example if following be two inputs:
 input1.txt

```
22211 21111 11111 
22222 22222 11111
22222 11111 23211
```

input2.txt

```
22211 21111  
22222 20002 
22222 11111
```

I want my output be like:

```
22211 21111 11111 22211 21111 
22222 22222 11111 22222 20002 
22222 11111 23211 22222 20002
```

but the problem is when I use this command:

```
paste input1.txt input2.txt > out.txt
```

then there is a gap on out.txt where two files joined together like:

```
22211 21111 11111     22211 21111 
22222 22222 11111     22222 20002 
22222 11111 23211     22222 20002
```

what should I do to not see this gap?
I should mention that I have 37 txt files( hap1.txt hap2.txt ..hap37.txt)
which I wish to join them together side by side. any suggestion please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That gap is a tab. Just tell `paste` that you want to use a space as delimiter instead of tabs. From [`man paste`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html):

```
-d, --delimiters=LIST
      reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs
```

Example:

```
$ paste -d' ' input1 input2
22211 21111 11111 22211 21111  
22222 22222 11111 22222 20002 
22222 11111 23211 22222 11111
```

Comment: and if I want to run this command for 37 files at one time then what should I do?

Comment: Probably something like: `paste hap{1..37}.txt`

Comment: I used this command:paste -d' ' input1 input2   but again there is a gap, but this time the gap is only at first row and is smaller. whay is that?

Comment: @ramin your input file probably has a space or two at the end.

Comment: @ramin check again. Use `od -c` if it helps.

Comment: i checked it but i do not know how to interprate the result

Comment: See if you find more than one blank before a `\n`.

Comment: i am putting the result in my post. can you look at that please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29984/discussion-between-ramin-and-muru).